# How can I update or adjust the evaluation function after each generation in a DEAP genetic algorithm

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, genetic-algorithm, deap

I have made a genetic algorithm using DEAP package. My evaluation function looks like the following

```
Arch = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

def evalComp(individual):
    compare = ((np.absolute( Arch[3] - individual[3])+np.absolute( Arch[4] - individual[4])+np.absolute( Arch[5] - individual[5])+np.absolute( Arch[6] - individual[6])+np.absolute( Arch[7] - individual[7])+np.absolute( Arch[8] - individual[8])+np.absolute( Arch[9] - individual[9])+np.absolute( Arch[10] - individual[10])+np.absolute( Arch[11] - individual[11])+np.absolute( Arch[12] - individual[12])+np.absolute( Arch[13] - individual[13])+np.absolute( Arch[14] - individual[14])+np.absolute( Arch[15] - individual[15])+np.absolute( Arch[16] - individual[16])+np.absolute( Arch[17] - individual[17])+np.absolute( Arch[18] - individual[18])+np.absolute( Arch[19] - individual[19]))/17)
    return compare,
```

What I would like to do is change "Arch" to a different numpy array after each generation. My problem is "g" is defined by the main function and "evalComp" is outside the main function. Here is the full GA:

```
import random
import time
from deap import base
from deap import creator
from deap import tools
import numpy as np
from secrets import randbelow

start_time = time.time() # Calculates runtime
creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(-1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("attr_int", randbelow, (10))
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, 
                 toolbox.attr_int, 20) 

toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

# Archetype

Arch = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

pop = toolbox.population(n=5)
pop = (pop)
print(pop)
print("\n")
print("\n")

def evalComp(individual):
    compare = ((np.absolute( Arch[3] - individual[3])+np.absolute( Arch[4] - individual[4])+np.absolute( Arch[5] - individual[5])+np.absolute( Arch[6] - individual[6])+np.absolute( Arch[7] - individual[7])+np.absolute( Arch[8] - individual[8])+np.absolute( Arch[9] - individual[9])+np.absolute( Arch[10] - individual[10])+np.absolute( Arch[11] - individual[11])+np.absolute( Arch[12] - individual[12])+np.absolute( Arch[13] - individual[13])+np.absolute( Arch[14] - individual[14])+np.absolute( Arch[15] - individual[15])+np.absolute( Arch[16] - individual[16])+np.absolute( Arch[17] - individual[17])+np.absolute( Arch[18] - individual[18])+np.absolute( Arch[19] - individual[19]))/17)
    return compare,

toolbox.register("evaluate", evalComp)
toolbox.register("mate", tools.cxUniform)
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutShuffleIndexes, indpb=0.05)
toolbox.register("select", tools.selTournament, tournsize=4)

def main():
    random.seed(43)
    pop = toolbox.population(n=50)


    print("Start of evolution")

    fitnesses = list(map(toolbox.evaluate, pop))
    for ind, fit in zip(pop, fitnesses):
        ind.fitness.values = fit

    print(" Evaluated %i individuals" % len(pop))

    CXPB, MUTPB = 0.5, 0.3
    fits = [ind.fitness.values[0] for ind in pop]
    global g
    g = 0
    while max(fits) > 0 and g < 50:
        g = g + 1
        print("-- Generation %i --" % g)
        offspring = toolbox.select(pop, len(pop))
        offspring = list(map(toolbox.clone, offspring))
        for child1, child2 in zip(offspring[::2], offspring[1::2]):
            if random.random() < CXPB:
                toolbox.mate(child1, child2, 0.3)
                del child1.fitness.values
                del child2.fitness.values

        for mutant in offspring:
            if random.random() < MUTPB:
                toolbox.mutate(mutant)
                del mutant.fitness.values

        invalid_ind = [ind for ind in offspring if not ind.fitness.valid]
        fitnesses = map(toolbox.evaluate, invalid_ind)
        for ind, fit in zip(invalid_ind, fitnesses):
            ind.fitness.values = fit

        print(" Evaluated %i individuals" % len(invalid_ind))

        pop[:] = offspring
        fits = [ind.fitness.values[0] for ind in pop]

        length = len(pop)
        mean = sum(fits) / length
        sum2 = sum(x*x for x in fits)
        std = abs(sum2 / length - mean**2)**0.5

        print(" Min %s" % min(fits))
        print(" Max %s" % max(fits))
        print(" Avg %s" % mean)
        print(" Std %s" % std)

    print("-- End of (successful) evolution --")
    print("\n")
    print("\n")
    print("Archetype",  Arch)

    print("\n")
    best_ind = tools.selBest(pop, 1)[0]
    print("Best individual is %s, %s" % (best_ind, best_ind.fitness.values))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Thanks in advance!!

UPDATE:

@usernumber has suggested defining `Arch` inside the generation loop. I have attempted this and it seems to print the new `Arch` after each loop, however the `evalComp` still uses the original definition of `Arch` to calculate fitness. If I remove the original `Arch = np.array([...])` line, I get `NameError: name 'Arch' is not defined`.

What I want is for `Arch` from inside the generation loop to be used in the evaluation function:`evalComp()`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `Arch` to the parameters of your evaluation function

```
def evalComp(individual, Arch):
    compare = ...
    return compare,
```

Then when you register the evaluation function in the toolbox, pass Arch to it

```
toolbox.register("evaluate", evalComp, Arch)
```

Since `Arch` points to the numpy array, when you modify its contents, `eval` will access the new contents of the array. So in the generation loop, you just have to set the value of `Arch` to whatever you want it to be

```
while g<50:
    Arch = np.random.rand(10)
```

---

Full code then becomes

```
import random
import time
from deap import base
from deap import creator
from deap import tools
import numpy as np
from secrets import randbelow

start_time = time.time() # Calculates runtime
creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(-1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("attr_int", randbelow, (10))
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, 
                 toolbox.attr_int, 20) 

toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

# Archetype

Arch = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

pop = toolbox.population(n=5)
pop = (pop)
print(pop)
print("\n")
print("\n")

def evalComp(individual, Arch):
    compare = ((np.absolute( Arch[3] - individual[3])+np.absolute( Arch[4] - individual[4])+np.absolute( Arch[5] - individual[5])+np.absolute( Arch[6] - individual[6])+np.absolute( Arch[7] - individual[7])+np.absolute( Arch[8] - individual[8])+np.absolute( Arch[9] - individual[9])+np.absolute( Arch[10] - individual[10])+np.absolute( Arch[11] - individual[11])+np.absolute( Arch[12] - individual[12])+np.absolute( Arch[13] - individual[13])+np.absolute( Arch[14] - individual[14])+np.absolute( Arch[15] - individual[15])+np.absolute( Arch[16] - individual[16])+np.absolute( Arch[17] - individual[17])+np.absolute( Arch[18] - individual[18])+np.absolute( Arch[19] - individual[19]))/17)
    return compare,

toolbox.register("evaluate", evalComp, Arch)
toolbox.register("mate", tools.cxUniform)
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutShuffleIndexes, indpb=0.05)
toolbox.register("select", tools.selTournament, tournsize=4)

def main():
    random.seed(43)
    pop = toolbox.population(n=50)


    print("Start of evolution")

    fitnesses = list(map(toolbox.evaluate, pop))
    for ind, fit in zip(pop, fitnesses):
        ind.fitness.values = fit

    print(" Evaluated %i individuals" % len(pop))

    CXPB, MUTPB = 0.5, 0.3
    fits = [ind.fitness.values[0] for ind in pop]
    global g
    g = 0
    while max(fits) > 0 and g < 50:
        g = g + 1
        Arch = np.random.rand(20)
        print("-- Generation %i --" % g)
        offspring = toolbox.select(pop, len(pop))
        offspring = list(map(toolbox.clone, offspring))
        for child1, child2 in zip(offspring[::2], offspring[1::2]):
            if random.random() < CXPB:
                toolbox.mate(child1, child2, 0.3)
                del child1.fitness.values
                del child2.fitness.values

        for mutant in offspring:
            if random.random() < MUTPB:
                toolbox.mutate(mutant)
                del mutant.fitness.values

        invalid_ind = [ind for ind in offspring if not ind.fitness.valid]
        fitnesses = map(toolbox.evaluate, invalid_ind)
        for ind, fit in zip(invalid_ind, fitnesses):
            ind.fitness.values = fit

        print(" Evaluated %i individuals" % len(invalid_ind))

        pop[:] = offspring
        fits = [ind.fitness.values[0] for ind in pop]

        length = len(pop)
        mean = sum(fits) / length
        sum2 = sum(x*x for x in fits)
        std = abs(sum2 / length - mean**2)**0.5

        print(" Min %s" % min(fits))
        print(" Max %s" % max(fits))
        print(" Avg %s" % mean)
        print(" Std %s" % std)

    print("-- End of (successful) evolution --")
    print("\n")
    print("\n")
    print("Archetype",  Arch)

    print("\n")
    best_ind = tools.selBest(pop, 1)[0]
    print("Best individual is %s, %s" % (best_ind, best_ind.fitness.values))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: If I do this, how can I get the contents of the array to update after each generation. For example: for generation 1 I want ```Arch = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])```, for generation 2 I want ```Arch =  np.array([0,0,0,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2])```, for generation 3 I want ```Arch =  np.array([0,0,0,5,3,1,4,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,4,5])```etc. Arch should update to a different array after each loop.

Comment: In your generation loop (`while g<50`), add a line to update `Arch`.

Comment: @badam I can't parse python written without line breaks. See updated answer.

Comment: Sorry about the formating (I'm new at this)  Your code seems to work however I do need Arch to be a specific np.array for each generation, not a random one. I attempted an `if` `elif` statement in the generation loop but could not get it to work. ```if g < 5:  Arch = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])```   ```elif g < 10:...```

Comment: You can replace the line `Arch = np.random.rand(20)` by whatever you need `Arch` to be. I feel like this is a different question you are asking now.

Comment: Also, I just realized it keeps using the original definition of ```Arch``` that is outside ```def main()``` to do the comparison in ```def evalComp(individual, Arch): ...```. I guess this is why when I change ```Arch``` within the loop it has no effect on the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203554/discussion-between-badam-and-usernumber).